# Как можно получить коллекцию, которая находится внутри другой коллецкции

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Использую Firebase в своем проекте на React. Как можно получить данные из коллекции, которая находится внутри другой коллекции.
Допустим, есть коллекция product, внутри которой есть документ и внутри этого документа есть другая коллекция, к которой мне и нужно получить доступ, может, есть какая-то функция, чтобы ее получить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]